# Is there a function $f$ such that $f^ {-1} (x) = (f(x)) ^ {-1}$?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Let $f(x)=y$, then$f^ {-1} (y) = x$ and $(f(x)) ^ {-1} = \frac{1}{f(x)}$

Comment: You might state to start with `Let $f$ be a function having an inverse $f^{-1}$', then pose your problem.  A well formulated question sometimes solves itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my (amateur) answer:

if $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$, then $f\left(\frac{1}{f\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)}\right)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$.

But $f\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=x$.
Therefore $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$.

So $f(x)$ is in the class of functions such that $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$.

Comment: For $f(x)=x$, we have $f^ {-1} (x) = x$ and $(f(x)) ^ {-1} = \frac{1}{x}$ therefore $f^ {-1} (x) \ne (f(x)) ^ {-1}$.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Sorry then! I'll edit my answer. I still think the preceding section is correct though.